# i cant convert mysql json data to my java type

Tags: java, mysql, json

Could not deserialize string to java type: BasicJavaType(com.jxufe.course_scheduling_system.entity.auxiliary_type.TeacherPreference)
hibernate give me this error

i have a user type TeacherPreference defind like this:

```java
public
class TeacherPreference {
    private ArrayList<BasicScheduleItem> no_class_time;

    public
    TeacherPreference(ArrayList<BasicScheduleItem> nct){
        this.no_class_time = nct;
    }

    public boolean equals(TeacherPreference preference) {
        return this.no_class_time.equals(preference.no_class_time);
    }
}
```

and its used here

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table( name = "teacher" )
public
class Teacher {

    @Id//ID标识
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )//自增标识
    private Long teacher_ID;

    @Column( name = "name" )//列标识
    private String name;

    @JdbcTypeCode( SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column( name = "class_IDs", columnDefinition = "json" )
    private ArrayList<Long> class_IDs;

    @JdbcTypeCode( SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column( name = "preference" )
    private TeacherPreference preference;



    public
    String toJson() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }

}
```

when i try to convert at here

```
@Service
public
class TeacherService {

    @Autowired
    TeacherRepository repository;

    public
    String getByID(Long ID) {
        String res;
        try {
            res = repository.findById(ID).get().toJson();
            System.out.println(res);
            return res;
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

i got this error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not deserialize string to java type: BasicJavaType(com.jxufe.course_scheduling_system.entity.auxiliary_type.TeacherPreference)

how to fix it and why

Comment: are you experiencing an IllegalArgumentException from JacksonJsonFormatMapper in your stacktrace? Please, can you report it fully?